# Nested GROUP BY optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT trip_id, MAX(cnt) FROM 
(
    SELECT trip_id, stop_id, COUNT(*) as cnt 
    FROM operation_ticket_part_stops 
    GROUP BY trip_id, stop_id
) AS t
GROUP BY trip_id
```

Result is (this is the result I want):

```
trip_id MAX(cnt)
10072 2
10583 1
**10607 11**
10608 8
10609 13
10612 5
11170 1
11239 1
11675 30
...
```

Result for subquery is:

```
trip_id stop_id cnt
...
10607 11234 11
10607 11235 10
10607 11236 10
10607 11237 11
10607 11238 9
10607 11239 7
...
```

Is there any way I can avoid subquery here (and optimize maybe?). Database: MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
SELECT trip_id, stop_id, COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM operation_ticket_part_stops 
GROUP BY trip_id, stop_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This query sorts your sub query and takes the first record only (which holds the same result as the Max)

Comment: But I want multiple rows returned. (One row for trip_id)

Comment: @MariusGrigaitis Don't get the question. Please include sample data and expected result in question.

Comment: The included data is the result I expect. I just want to avoid subquery. I clarified it in my question.

Comment: If this is not what you're looking for, you need the subquery.